# ConnectionError on multi-Docker app (Streamlit + FastAPI) when deployed on Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose, fastapi, streamlit

I have a multi-Docker application with a Streamlit frontend and a FastAPI backend deployed on Heroku: https://morning-everglades-39854.herokuapp.com/

The code is on GitHub: https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain (add an [OPENAPI_API_KEY](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys) to a [.env](https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain/blob/main/.env.template) file if you want to reproduce).

It has:

- a [frontend](https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain/tree/main/frontend) folder with a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain/blob/main/frontend/Dockerfile) and [streamlit_app.py](https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain/blob/main/frontend/streamlit_app.py) file
- a [backend](https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain/tree/main/backend) folder with a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain/blob/main/backend/Dockerfile) and an [api.py](https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain/blob/main/backend/api.py) file
- a [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain/blob/main/docker-compose.yml) file
- a [heroku.yml](https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain/blob/main/heroku.yml) file

locally, I can do:

```
docker compose build
docker compose up
```

and go to http://172.19.0.3:8501, ask a math question and get an answer:

[image: app working locally]

But after deploying the app on Heroku with

```
heroku create
heroku stack:set container
git push heroku main
heroku open
```

and trying the same math question there, I get the error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /ask (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9f5e00d040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/streamlit_app.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
File "/app/streamlit_app.py", line 24, in main
    response = requests.request("POST", host, headers=header, data=payload)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 520, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
```

How do I fix this?

**edit**:

To answer the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76155032/connectionerror-on-multi-docker-app-streamlit-fastapi-when-deployed-on-herok#comment134302464_76155032) of [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17865804/chris):

> [Could you] explain what `api` represents in `host = "http://api:8080/ask"` at line 21 of `streamlit_app.py`

I based my code on [this repository](https://github.com/davidefiocco/streamlit-fastapi-model-serving) with a similar setup. In `streamlit-fastapi-model-serving/streamlit/ui.py` there you will see at lines 9-10:

```
# interact with FastAPI endpoint
backend = "http://fastapi:8000/segmentation"
```

It is my understanding (but I might be wrong in this) that `fastapi` here refers to the [name of the service/container as defined in the docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/davidefiocco/streamlit-fastapi-model-serving/blob/c60fe1aa8c4e6b327bb61b7491c9b3fa32675588/docker-compose.yml#L4).

Similary, see [this question with a similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75237114/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-failed-to-establish-a-new-connection-errno-111) where the solution was to use `host = 'http://container_2:8000'` where `container_2` is the name of the service in the docker-compose.yml file.

Since I have an [`api` service defined in my `docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain/blob/4b1b2e2fbd5ae1103cb3eed39688a81c2f213000/docker-compose.yml#L18), I named my host `http://ask:8080`, which works locally but doesn't work on Heroku.

**edit 2**:

[M.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11612918/m-o) said:

> You're not actually running your FastAPI application. To run multiple processes, you have to specify them in the run: section in heroku.yml

[I have done that,](https://github.com/BioGeek/streamlit-fastapi-langchain/blob/4efd427cb388c0c44fd1ec6e26152064c4d5f4d7/heroku.yml#L8) but the same problem still persists.

The error is now slightly different. It says:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080):
```

instead of

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api', port=8080):
```

Comment: I would suggest using `sessions` with `requests`, or [`Client` in `httpx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), and adjust the max retries (see [here](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#usage_1) on how to do this in `httpx` and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15431044) on how to do it using `requests`).

Comment: @Chris see my edit to the question above to answer your questions.

Comment: You're not actually running your FastAPI application. To run multiple processes, you have to specify them [in the `run:` section in `heroku.yml`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#run-defining-the-processes-to-run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `docker-compose` locally, it will set up a [network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) for you (`deploy_network` in your case). As such, all the `services` will be routable by default with their name (`web` and `api` in this case).

On Heroku [Docker images run in dynos the same way that slugs do, and under the same constraints](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime):

> Network linking of dynos is not supported.

When you deploy two Docker images, two dynos will be spun up, one for each container based on their respective image. As such, they will not be networked together privately.

What you could possibly do is first deploy the `api` image, get back the public URL assigned to it along with any TLS termination configuration, then set that as a variable inside the `web` image and use that as the connection URL for the `web` container.

However, this would potentially route those requests over the Internet.

Another option could be to run both the `api` and `web` on the same HTTP server instance in the same container. For example, serving the `api` code under `/api` route and the web under `/app` route. You would only run one image that contains both the `web` and `api` code combined.