# Can't get one pod to talk to another pod (ScrapyRT communication in Kubernetes not working)

Tags: python, node.js, docker, kubernetes, scrapy

I'm managing a Kubernetes cluster and want **Pod1** to make API calls  to **Pod2** and **Pod3** (but **Pod1** - **Pod3** fails!):

1. **Pod1**: A Jupyter Notebook environment to test connections.
2. **Pod2**: An Express.js app running on port 8000, exposed on port 80 via the `express-backend-service`.
3. **Pod3**: A python [scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) application with [ScrapyRT](https://scrapyrt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) listening on port 14805, exposed on port 80 via `getcookie-14805-service`.

### Pod2 Service and Deployment (express-backend-service):

##### express-deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: express-app-deployment
spec:
  #...
  containers:
  - name: express-app
    image: privaterepo/myproject-backend:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8000
    #...
```

##### express-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: express-backend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: express-app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8000
  type: ClusterIP
```

### Pod3 Service and Deployment (getcookie-14805-service):

##### getcookie-14805-deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: getcookie-pod
  labels:
    app: getcookie-pod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: getcookie-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: getcookie-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: getcookie-pod
        image: privaterepo/myproject-scrapy:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always  # Ensure the latest image is always pulled
        ports:
        - containerPort: 14805
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: scrapy-env
        env:
        - name: SCRAPYRT_PORT
          value: "14805"
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: docker-credentials
```

##### getcookie-14805-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: getcookie-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: getcookie-pod
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 14805
  type: ClusterIP
```

#### Kubernetes Logs

`kubectl get svc`:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME                                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
express-backend-service                      ClusterIP   10.99.145.37    <none>        80/TCP    2d
getcookie-service                            ClusterIP   10.106.14.183   <none>        80/TCP    29m
kubernetes                                   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   2d
```

pods
`kubectl get pods`

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME                                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
express-app-deployment-6896ff994c-gl4pd                         1/1     Running   3 (4h4m ago)    2d
getcookie-pod-59b8575ffc-8dcqb                                  1/1     Running   0               28m
jupyter-debug-pod                                               1/1     Running   3 (7h33m ago)   6d9h
```

pod3 logs (getcookie-pod-59b8575ffc-8dcqb):

```
$ kubectl logs getcookie-pod-59b8575ffc-8dcqb -f
2024-01-08 06:26:07+0000 [-] Log opened.
2024-01-08 06:26:07+0000 [-] Site starting on 14805
2024-01-08 06:26:07+0000 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7fc2139a44f0>
2024-01-08 06:26:07+0000 [-] Running with reactor: AsyncioSelectorReactor.
2024-01-08 06:56:24+0000 [-] "127.0.0.1" - - [08/Jan/2024:06:56:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 167 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
```

That curl log above showed up only after I did an `exec` into the pod and ran this:

```
curl http://localhost:14805
```

#### Update 1/7/2024

Trying to directly curl the getcookie-service doesn't work:

`curl http://getcookie-service`
Output:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to getcookie-service port 80: Connection refused
```

### Issue:

I can successfully send requests from **Pod1** to **Pod2** using the service name **http://express-backend-service/api**. However, when attempting to connect to **Pod3** using a similar approach, I get a connection error.

Here's the Python code snippet used in **Pod1** to connect to **Pod3**:

```
def getCookie(userId):
    endpoint = 'http://getcookie-14805-service.default/crawl.json?spider_name=getCookie&url=http://images.google.com/'
    post = {
        "request": {
            "url": "http://images.google.com/",
            "meta": {'userId': userId},
            "callback": "parse",
            "dont_filter": "True"
        },
        "spider_name": "getCookie"
    }
    try:
        response = requests.post(endpoint, json=post).json()
        return response['items'][0]['finalItems']
    except Exception as e:
        print('getCookie error:', e)
        return None

user = '6010dga53294c92c981ef3y576'
getCookie(user)
```

Error received:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='getcookie-14805-service.default', port=80): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /crawl.json?spider_name=getCookie&url=http://images.google.com/ 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fde7a6cc7f0>: Failed 
to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Why can I successfully make calls from **Pod1** to **Pod2** but not from **Pod1** to **Pod3**?

I expected the Kubernetes services to facilitate inter-pod communication. Do I need additional configuration?

Comment: Can you refer to this [GITlink](https://github.com/brody192/reverse-proxy/blob/main/README.md)  and do the changes accordingly as Both the frontend and backend need to listen on fixed ports 8000. Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75237114/) by Vladislav Mikhailov for more information.

Comment: Does the second Deployment have a matching `template: { metadata: { labels: { app: getcookie-14805 } } }`?  Is the process there actually listening on a fixed port 14805?

Comment: @HemanthKumar I tried to do the GITlink solution but I'm not so familiar with Caddy files and was not able to complete it.  I did check the SO and found despite writing the endpoint as 'http://127.0.0.1:80/api" vs "http://service-endpoint:80" it still never connects to the pod3.

Comment: @rom : can you run this Command `kubectl logs <pod 3 name>` to  see the pod logs if there are any errors or indications of connection problems.

Comment: @HemanthKumar, Here's the logs:
$ k logs getcookie-pod-59b8575ffc-8dcqb -f
2024-01-08 06:26:07+0000 [-] Log opened.
2024-01-08 06:26:07+0000 [-] Site starting on 14805
2024-01-08 06:26:07+0000 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7fc2139a44f0>
2024-01-08 06:26:07+0000 [-] Running with reactor: AsyncioSelectorReactor.
2024-01-08 06:56:24+0000 [-] "127.0.0.1" - - [08/Jan/2024:06:56:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 167 "-" "curl/7.68.0"

The curl is due to running "# curl http://localhost:14805" otherwise nothing penetrates to the server logs.  I've tried everything :(

Comment: from inside the pod, run a test to the actual endpoint using localhost instead of service name

Comment: @rom : Can you run the above test as suggested by P Ekambaram

Comment: @rom : for conection refused error can check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36191539/19230181) by sixty4bit. Seems to be port 80 is not accepting , you need to do some work arounds as shown in this SO.

Comment: @HemanthKumar  Thank you for replying.  Unfortunately, none of those solutions mentioned in that SO worked for me.  I have tried localhost, 127.0.0.1, the service name, the service name with ports, enabling required the Dockerfile, but I still cannot connect into the scrapy-pod.